# Remove array elements matching element data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have
`stone = [];`

`stoneB.playerId = players[player.playerId].playerId`

I push new elements into stone by
`stone.push(stoneB)`

How would I go about removing all of the elements from stone that match `stoneB.playerId` for a given player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is probably your best bet here:

```
stone = stone.filter(d => d.playerId !== stoneB.playerId)
```

or more generally:

```
function remove(stone, playerId) {
  return stone.filter(d => d.playerId !== playerId);
}

stone = remove(stone, stoneB.playerId);
```